# Windows 7 on top of VMware - RabbitMQ

Tags: windows-7, vmware, services, erlang

I`m running windows 7 on top of VMware.
I installed Erlang and then RabbitMQ and from some reason the RabbitMQ
starts and then stops.
I tried to check the port using netstat and RabbitMQ is the only one using it.
Anyone knows this?

Thanks

Update:
I`ve solved this at the end by removing and re-installing rabbitmq.
Still wierd.

Thanks all

Comment: What does the error log say? Look in _%APPDATA%\RabbitMQ\log_

Comment: I`ve solved this at the end by removing and re-installing rabbitmq.
Still wierd.